# How to set value of input when i press button in the table? Here i using laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.8

I want "nik" data to appear in the input text when I select the button in the modal table.

This is my fresh input :[img-input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P4g6.png)

And then, this is layout when i click button cari : [img-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyxWB.png)

When i click button "pilih", I want data "nik" to fill the value in the input text. My expectation : [img-expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0byNc.png)

Here my view - blank value of input:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm cari-karyawan px-3">Cari</button>
</div>
```

Here my modal view when i click button "pilih":

```
@foreach ($karyawans as $karyawan)
<tr>
    <th scope="row"> {{ $loop->iteration }} </th>
    <td> {{ $karyawan->nik }} </td>
    <td> {{ $karyawan->nm_karyawan }} </td>
    <td> {{ $karyawan->rs->nm_rs }} </td>
    <td> {{ $karyawan->unit->nm_unit }} </td>
    <td> {{ $karyawan->jabatan->nm_jabatan }} </td>
    <td> 
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-nik="{{ $karyawan->nik }}" id="btnPilih">Pilih</button> 
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And then, this is my javascript code :

```
$('.cari-karyawan').on('click', function () {

  var nik = $(this).data('nik');

  $("#btnPilih").click(function(event) { 
    $("#nik").val(nik);
        $('#nik').val(nik); 
        console.log(nik)
  }); 

  $("#cariKaryawan").modal("show");
});
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..

```
  $(".btnPilih").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
    var nik = $(this).data("nik");
    document.getElementById("nik").value = nik;
    })
  });
```